# Верно ли составлено предложение и поставлены знаки пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика

Я бы хотел узнать, конечно, если это возможно:
когда ожидается поставка в ваш магазин, смартфона Sumsung Galaxy S7? Спасибо.

или будет вернее "..на сколько это возможно:" ?

Comment: "чи" в вопросе - совершенно не нужно. Это не по-русски.  Вообще в русском языке не нужно столько вежливых форм.

Comment: Забавно, даже не слышал про это "чи"!))

Comment: Никто не написал про то, что сокращать многоточие до двух точек неряшливо и неоправданно. (Сам даже одно время так делал, следуя общей "моде", но понял, что это неправильно.)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Забавно, даже не слышал про это "чи"!* - чи -это по-украински. ***"чи вiрно"*** - это "верно ли". Причем и в украинском грамматика подобным образом составленной фразы вызывала бы вопросы. Не знаю, может на Кубани так говорят, но не во Львове. А суржик я знаю плохо. ))) Хотя и суржики сами по себе очень разные - В Одессе совсем не тот, что в Краснодаре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не править ничего, кроме пунктуации, то так.
***Здравствуйте. Я бы хотел узнать, конечно если это возможно, когда ожидается поставка в ваш магазин смартфона Sumsung Galaxy S7?***
Запятая после "магазин" совершенно непонятная и очевидно ненужная.
Запятую после "конечно", думаю, тоже надо убрать, т.к. вводное слово стоит в начале вставного придаточного, которое само по себе близко по значению к вводным словам. Но по большому счету оно, это "конечно", тут вообще не на месте.
Вопросительный знак в конце можно оставить, но лучше и тут обойтись точкой.

Но вообще говоря, такое обилие псевдовежливых форм не свойственно современному русскому языку. Есть иные способы выражения вежливости, не по-японски, чай, общаемся.
Я бы сократил Вашу фразу до следующей.
***Здравствуйте. Я бы хотел узнать, когда ожидается поставка в ваш магазин смартфона Sumsung Galaxy S7.*** 
Тут и вопросов по пунктуации не возникает.

Ну или вообще написать совсем по-другому, как вон ddbug предлагает.

> или будет вернее "..на сколько это возможно:"

Ни в коем случае. Во-первых, не "на сколько", а "насколько", а во-вторых, по стилю еще хуже получается. Лучше вообще, как писал, эти излишества выкинуть и писать просто и понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Не мучайтесь. Напишите просто: "Прошу сообщить когда в вашем магазине появится  Samsung Galaxy S7. С уважением, Вася Иванов. " 
И всё.

Comment: Запятую только не забывайте перед "когда".